# Dojo unable to get element by ID

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I was trying to set a button event listener using Dojo. Once the button onclick, it will perform geocode function. Here are the codes:

```
require (["esri/map", "esri/dijit/Scalebar", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/dijit/Legend","dojo/_base/array","dojo/parser","dijit/layout/BorderContainer","dijit/layout/ContentPane","dijit/layout/AccordionContainer","esri/InfoTemplate","dojo/dom-construct",
    "esri/tasks/locator","esri/graphic","esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol","esri/symbols/Font","esri/symbols/TextSymbol","esri/Color","dojo/number","dojo/dom","dijit/registry",
    "dijit/form/Button","dijit/form/Textarea", "dojo/domReady!"],

function(Map, Scalebar, FeatureLayer,Legend, arrayUtils, parser, BorderContainer, ContentPane, AccordionContainer, InfoTemplate, domConstruct,
        Locator,Graphic,SimpleMarkerSymbol,Font,TextSymbol,Font,TextSymbol,Color,number,dom,registry, Button, Textarea){
```

And my button event listener:

```
 registry.byId("locate").on("click", locate);
```

However, I am getting this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){var c=arguments,d=c,f=c[0],g,e;e=a.length;var h;if(!(this instanceof c.callee))return v(c);
if(b&&(f&&f.preamble||this.preamble)){h=Array(a.length);h[0]=c;for(g=0;;){if(f=c[0])(f=f.preamble)&&(c=f.apply(this,c)||c);f=a[g].prototype;(f=f.hasOwnProperty("preamble")&&f.preamble)&&(c=f.apply(this,c)||c);if(++g==e)break;h[g]=c}}for(g=e-1;0<=g;--g)f=a[g],(f=(e=f._meta)?e.ctor:f)&&f.apply(this,h?h[g]:c);(f=this.postscript)&&f.apply(this,d)} has no method 'byId'
```

My JsFiddle: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/snn0axqq/)

Any guides? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any ideas? I could not figure out why is it so :(

Comment: is the "locate" element a dijit widget ? (because registry only applies to dijit widgets, dom.byId should be used for dom elements instead). If so, has the dojo parsing been done when you set your listener ?

Comment: My locate button as such:<button id="locate" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">Locate</button>

Comment: @PatrickRuzand I got the same error message no matter I changed to dom.byId or registry.byId

Comment: there is no enough information here to know what is the problem. have you tried to test the on click function? like to put instead if the locate function, put a function that do and alert("") or a console log to check if the onlcik works if this works then you need to supply us with more code.

Comment: Nope. The onclick does not work. It's not only does not work, when I put in the registry.byId() codes, it breaks my other features. It just show that error message after my map finish loading

Comment: and regarding the parsing: has it been done when your code is invoked ? Anyway, a jsfiddle would be needed

Comment: Here you go, the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/snn0axqq/ If I comment out the registry that line, all my features working

Comment: @dorinaji I have provided the jsfiddle already. Please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/snn0axqq/9/) that works, the problem you are doing is that by mistake you added the `Font, TextSymbol` callback twice, this will conflict the registry call back

```
require(["esri/map", "esri/dijit/Scalebar", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/dijit/Legend", "dojo/_base/array", "dojo/parser", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer", "esri/InfoTemplate", "dojo/dom-construct",
    "esri/tasks/locator", "esri/graphic", "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol", "esri/symbols/Font", "esri/symbols/TextSymbol", "esri/Color", "dojo/number", "dojo/dom", "dijit/registry",
    "dijit/form/Button", "dijit/form/Textarea", "dojo/domReady!"],

function (Map, Scalebar, FeatureLayer, Legend, arrayUtils, parser, BorderContainer, ContentPane, AccordionContainer, InfoTemplate, domConstruct,
Locator, Graphic, SimpleMarkerSymbol, Font, TextSymbol, Font, TextSymbol, Color, number, dom, registry) {
```

Comment: I see. I was so stupid for this careless mistake :( Thanks a lot!